# Getting Invalid Identifier error when I do not use ALIAS in the second Sub Query after LEFT JOIN

Tags: sql, subquery, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, alias

I am joining two subquery tables (Code below) using LEFT JOIN, and I am getting

> SQL compilation error: error line 72 at position 19 invalid identifier
> 'PO.OI_EBELN' error

when I do not use ALIAS for `OI_EBELN||''||OI_EBELP`. Just want to know what's the reason for this? However, If I change the syntax for second subquery to this or Use ALIAS, I do not get any error

```
SELECT *, OI_EBELN||''||OI_EBELP,DAYSPASTSTATISTICALSHIPDATE FROM"TERADATA"."PRD_DWH_VIEW_LMT"."PURCHASE_ORDER_V" WHERE OI_EBELN||''||OI_EBELP IN
```

Here is the original code:

```
SELECT*
FROM (SELECT *, PO||''||POLINE AS CONCAT_SFR  
FROM "TERADATA"."PRD_DWH_VIEW_LMT"."SC_FILL_RATE_METRIC_VIEW" 
WHERE PO||''||POLINE IN('50025171063',
'50025171062',
'50025213631',
'50025147141',)) AS SFR
LEFT JOIN 
(SELECT OI_EBELN||''||OI_EBELP,DAYSPASTSTATISTICALSHIPDATE FROM"TERADATA"."PRD_DWH_VIEW_LMT"."PURCHASE_ORDER_V" 
WHERE OI_EBELN||''||OI_EBELP IN('50025171063',
'50025171062',
'50025213631',
'50025147141',)) AS PO
ON SFR.CONCAT_SFR= PO.OI_EBELN||''||OI_EBELP
```

Can anyone please advise the reason for the invalid identifier error?

I am looking to identify the reason for the invalid identifier error. Is it because without * or ALIAS, the complier takes OI_EBELN as the column name and cannot locate it?

Comment: Not sure, but I think the join would look more like this: `ON PO.OI_EBELN||''||PO.OI_EBELP`. Anyway, just alias that in your select and join on the alias like you mentioned. Would look cleaner. Why is this part of the concat? `||''||`

Comment: Sidenote, the Snowflake `CONCAT()` function allow you to concatenate more than two columns, so that might be cleaner than using `||` over and over. And just noticed you are using the alias PO on your left join, but "PO" also appears to be a column name per row 4 of your query. That seems problematic.

Comment: You haven't given the 1st column of PO a name (the DBMS will) & its only other column is DAYSPASTSTATISTICALSHIPDATE & one cannot dot an alias with an expression that is not a column identifier & the RHS of the final = parses (PO.OI_EBELN)||''||OI_EBELP.

Answer (score 0):

So making two CTE's to give some "fake data":

```
with SC_FILL_RATE_METRIC_VIEW(PO, POLINE, extra ) as (
    select * from values
    ('50025', '171062',  'extra a' )
), PURCHASE_ORDER_V(OI_EBELN, OI_EBELP, DAYSPASTSTATISTICALSHIPDATE) as (
    select * from values
    ('50025', '171062', 12 )
)
```

and using your SQL (changed to use these CTE's)

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT 
        *, 
        PO||''||POLINE AS CONCAT_SFR  
    FROM /*"TERADATA"."PRD_DWH_VIEW_LMT".*/SC_FILL_RATE_METRIC_VIEW
    WHERE PO||''||POLINE IN('50025171063',
        '50025171062',
        '50025213631',
        '50025147141')
) AS SFR
LEFT JOIN 
(   SELECT 
        OI_EBELN || '' || OI_EBELP,
        DAYSPASTSTATISTICALSHIPDATE 
    FROM /*"TERADATA"."PRD_DWH_VIEW_LMT".*/ PURCHASE_ORDER_V
    WHERE OI_EBELN || '' || OI_EBELP IN('50025171063',
        '50025171062',
        '50025213631',
        '50025147141')
) AS PO
ON SFR.CONCAT_SFR = PO.OI_EBELN||''||OI_EBELP
```

we get the same error:

> Error: invalid identifier 'PO.OI_EBELN' (line 29)

which is the final line, the "first column" of PO has no name, but also has already been transformed in the desired form, and lets also reuse that alias, in the WHERE clause, just so there is less room for getting things out of sync:

```
with SC_FILL_RATE_METRIC_VIEW(PO, POLINE, extra ) as (
    select * from values
    ('50025', '171062',  'extra a' )
), PURCHASE_ORDER_V(OI_EBELN, OI_EBELP, DAYSPASTSTATISTICALSHIPDATE) as (
    select * from values
    ('50025', '171062', 12 )
)
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT 
        *, 
        PO||''||POLINE AS CONCAT_SFR  
    FROM /*"TERADATA"."PRD_DWH_VIEW_LMT".*/SC_FILL_RATE_METRIC_VIEW
    WHERE CONCAT_SFR IN('50025171063',
        '50025171062',
        '50025213631',
        '50025147141')
) AS SFR
LEFT JOIN 
(   SELECT 
        OI_EBELN || '' || OI_EBELP as CONCAT_PO,
        DAYSPASTSTATISTICALSHIPDATE 
    FROM /*"TERADATA"."PRD_DWH_VIEW_LMT".*/ PURCHASE_ORDER_V
    WHERE CONCAT_PO IN('50025171063',
        '50025171062',
        '50025213631',
        '50025147141')
) AS PO
ON SFR.CONCAT_SFR = PO.CONCAT_PO
```

now gives results:

[image]

now, from the SQL you originally posted I cannot tell if you are really concatenating strings with an empty string, OR if there was some white space that has been striped out? But assuming it is an empty string, that parts should just be dropped:

```
PO||''||POLINE AS CONCAT_SFR
```

should just be:

```
PO || POLINE AS CONCAT_SFR
```

also given by default Snowflake is not case sensitive, we can use lower case, and have less shouting (total personal preference, but it does allow more white space around terms, and thus improve ability to read SQL imho):

```
po || poline as concat_sfr
```

The point I question is, that you are concatinating two values are comparing to a fixed set of strings, do you want different mixes of token to all be treated the same

```
select 
    $1 as po
    ,$2 as poline
    ,po || poline as concat_sfr
    ,CONCAT_SFR IN('50025171063', '50025171062', '50025213631') as sfr_in
from values
    ('50025','171062'),
    ('5002','5171062'),
    ('500','25171062'),
    ('50','025171062')
;
```

gives:

| PO | POLINE | CONCAT_SFR | SFR_IN |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 50025 | 171062 | 50025171062 | TRUE |
| 5002 | 5171062 | 50025171062 | TRUE |
| 500 | 25171062 | 50025171062 | TRUE |
| 50 | 025171062 | 50025171062 | TRUE |

Anyways this makes me think it might be cleaner to leave purchase order code and line code as numbers, unless letter tokens are valid, and even then two equijoin operations is faster than a string construction and comparison.